# Invoking A Property Inside A Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Hello I have a property inside a service reference called `public DateOfBirth

In my `IndexModel` class I want to use that property or at least the value without modifying the code in the service.

In the `IndexModel` class am I able to create a new property with Binding and required attribute and reference that property from the service so that I can bind it inside my HTML view?

Comment: When you say "service reference", do you mean a WCF/SOAP/ASMX "Web Service Reference"?

Comment: yes indeed that is what I'm utilizing more specifically Soap